# AngularJS ng-upload reset file selection

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am using a simple file upload as below:

```
<button type="file" ngf-select ng-model="fileData"
        ng-change="fileChanged(fileData)" name="file"  required >
    Select File
</button>
```

And I have another button which when clicked I want to clear out the file that was selected.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="clearFile()">
    Clear
</button>
```

I have the Controller code for button click as:

```
$scope.fileChanged = function(fileData) {
  if (fileData != undefined) {
    $scope.selectedFileName = fileData.name;
   }
}  

$scope.clearFile = function () {
        //None of these works
        //angular.element("input[type='file']").val(null);
       // $scope.fileData = [];
}
```

I have tried couple of options as I searched through previous posts but none of it works. What am I missing here.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abco2Lp0/

Comment: ` $scope.clearFile = function () { $scope.selectedFileName = null; }` this is working  i tried on your jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.clearFile = function () {
   $scope.fileData = [];
   $scope.selectedFileName = null;
   $scope.uploadedFile = [];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well this works to the extent the it clears out the UI, but the file is actually there in the file upload. See my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rx6zpqe9/ If on upload button click I can still see the file exists.

Comment: You are right, I think you should initialise $sope.uploadedFile too `$sope.uploadedFile = [];`